# Selecting the hour from a text column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a column with dates and times inputed like: `6/11/10 21:19`. The column is passed in as a text datatype. I am looking to select just the hours from each row in this column in mysql

I have tried to convert each row into a datetime format but it does not work.

The code I have tried is

`select DATEPART('h', convert(datetime, convert(char(30), order_placer_placed_time)))`

I am receiving a syntax error somewhere, but I still feel like my code is wrong. The select statement should return a value of 21.

Comment: Your code seriously looks like SQL Server, not MySQL.  What is your actual database?  Is this column _text_, or is it a proper datetime column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using MySQL, and this column is inputed as [i]text[/i]. The 3 values in this column are `4/15/12 1:49`, `10/13/12 2:22`, and `6/11/10 21:19`. My goal is to select the hours in each row. So the final output should be `1, 2, 21`.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `DATEPART`. It does however have `HOUR` which could be worth trying. I don't use MySQL, just googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - using `str_to_date()` and `hour()`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90f6e6287e60e61a5d6cd2b6686f81e6)**

```
select hour(str_to_Date('6/11/10 21:19','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'))

select hour(str_to_Date(order_placer_placed_time,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `STR_TO_DATE`, as suggested by @fa06, is probably the best way to go.  If, for some reason, you *can't* always parse your date strings, then we can try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('6/11/10 21:19', '.* ([0-9]+):.*', '$1') AS hour
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Moving forward, you should always try to store your dates and timestamps in proper date, datetime, or timestamp columns.